# Text Not Displaying Pygame 2.0.1

Tags: python, pygame

people of pygame,

I am creating a little program with pygame 2.0.1 and am trying to display text.

I think I have the correct code, although the text is not displaying.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame 
import os

pygame.init()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
pygame.display.set_caption("Egged")

font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 32)
FPS = 60


def draw_window():
    screen_text = font.render("Egged!", True, (27, 250, 87))
    WIN.blit(screen_text, (200, 200))
    WIN.fill((11, 68, 89))
    pygame.display.update()


def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()


    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

        draw_window()

    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And the text is not displaying!!!

Could you help?

Thanks!

Comment: You call `WIN.fill((11, 68, 89))` _after_ `blit`ing the text. You're literally rendering the text then painting over it. Put your fill first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order of the instructions. You have to clear the background before drawing the text:

```py
def draw_window():
    screen_text = font.render("Egged!", True, (27, 250, 87))
    WIN.fill((11, 68, 89))
    WIN.blit(screen_text, (200, 200))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't see the text because after you blit the text you fill the entire screen with this color

`WIN.fill((11, 68, 89))`

So it would work if you fill the color before bliting the text.